# Хук из сервиса не срабатывает

Tags: delphi, dll, service, hook

Мне необходимо обрабатывать сигналы сканера штрихкода. Необходимо, чтобы это было оформлено в виде службы. Я написал dll с глобальных хуком и в сервисе создаю поток `(TThread)` с окном для того, чтобы оно могло принимать сообщения из dll. Если я запускаю приложение как обычное, то все работает. А вот если как сервис, то нет. Ставил логи в функцию хука, и видно, что она вообще не срабатывает. Думаю, тут что-то с настройками службы. В свойствах службы выставлял галочку `взаимодействие с рабочим столом`, - не помогает. Где подкрутить, чтобы это заработало?

Comment: Праивильно - создать ещё одно приложение, которое будет запускаться от имени пользователя и связываться с сервисом, например, посредством tcp.

Comment: что это будет за приложение. поясните пожалуйста? зачем тогда сервис?  у меня есть dll в которой стоит глобальный хук на ввод с клавиатуры и есть сервис который подгружает dll.

Comment: Это приложение будет устанавливать хук. А зачем сервис - ну мало чего. Может такое ТЗ.

Comment: Ну нет. В этом случае сервис это рудимент. Необходимо что бы сервисом запускалось . Я же написал что просто приложением у меня все работает .

Comment: @gregor, обратите внимание на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815424/global-keyboard-hook-from-windows-service) и отмеченный ответ в нём. Неважно что там про .Net.

Comment: `взаимодействие с рабочим столом` было оставлено для совместимости и работало только в Windows Vista. В новых виндах сервисам недоступны ни ввод, ни рабочий стол по соображениям безопасности, не зависимо от того, от имени какого пользователя она запущена. Так что вам необходимо пересмотреть архитектуру вашего приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Программа-сервис по умолчанию запускается от пользователя с именем "Система". Подозреваю, что хук ставится не на всю Windows, а на конкретного пользователя (запустите одновременно два пользователя и проверьте передается ли между ними хук).

Соответственно в настройках сервиса есть вкладка "Log On", в ней пробуйте поставить текущего пользователя (+пароль, конечно).

PS.  *KoVadim* дал правильный совет. Считается очень дурным вкусом, когда у сервиса есть окошки.